How to get the list of users of a specific group having the list of all groups with users from an app
I would like to use data from my app to send notifications to users from specific group(s) by piping the output to xargs -l -i myapp notification:generate {} "System maintenance today starting at 4 PM"
My app can export list of groups with users in the form:
  - IT Systems Dep:
    - user1
    - user2
  - Medicine Dep:
    - user3
    - user4
    - user1

However, the app cannot export users of a specific group. How can I use sed or awk to get the list of users of a specific group, eg with the help of sed/awk/grep? So, I provide in the options the name of a specific group (or multiple groups) and obtaining the plain list of users, eg in case of 'Medicine Dep':
user3
user4
user1

Thanks!

can a user name include white space?

please update the question with the awk/sed code you've tried and the (wrong) results generated by said code

awk -v g='Medicine Dep:' '{sub(/^ *- */,"")} NR==1,$0==g {next} /:$/ {exit} 1'


{sub(/^ *- */,"")}: remove the spaces-spaces prefix
NR==1,$0==g {next}: skip all lines until the target group header (included)
/:$/ {exit}: exit on next group header
1: print everything else, that is, all lines between target group header and next group header (or end of file)

Note: if the spaces can also be tabs replace /^ *- */ with /^[[:space:]]*-[[:space:]]*/ or, if your awk is GNU awk, with /^\s*-\s*/.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -n '/:/h;//d;G;s/\s*- //;/Medicine Dep:/P' file

If the line contains : i.e. a group header, make a copy in the hold space and delete that line.
Append a group header to every other line.
Remove unwanted preamble.
If the group header appended to the current line contains Medicine Dep:, print the first amended line.
N.B. Because the -n option has been specified, automatic printing is suppressed. Also note, that once a d has been enacted and the current line deleted no further sed commands are processed.

@RenaudPacalet thanks, I always try not to build too much expectation for my solutions so I always start This might work for you (GNU sed), as for the use of \s instead of space, I guess experience tells me sometimes tabs sneak in and the \s covers these too. However as each line must have a - your solution or even just .*- would be suffice ([^-]*-  would be more accurate as the name might have a hyphen).

Oh, I completely missed the first line of your answer in which you indeed mention GNU sed. Sorry for that, I should read more carefully.

sed:
sed -n '/^  - <groupname>:$/,/^  - /s/^    - //p'


do range match

if line has user format, strip prefix and print



awk:
awk -F'  - ' '
    $1=="" { p = $2==q":"; next }
    p { print $2 }
' q='<groupname>'


split lines into fields by (space space hyphen space)
empty field 1 means field 2 contains a group name

set a flag if it is the desired group name
skip to next line


if flag is set, print user name (field 2)

Assumes  - does not appear in user name. If it can:
awk '
    /^  - / { p = $0=="  - "q":"; next }
    p { print substr($0,7) }
' q='<groupname>'


For sed, groupname is a regular expression.
For awk, groupname is a string.

With the help of AI, own brains and experiments I found 2 scenario:
(1) awk:
awk -v target_group="<groupname>" '
  /^  - / {
    in_target_group = ($0 ~ "^  - " target_group)
  }
  in_target_group && /^    - / {
    print $2
  }
'

(2a) sed:
sed -n '/^  - <groupname>.$/,/^  - [^-]/{/^    - /{s/^    - //p}; /^  - /d}'

(2b) or improved sed:
sed -En '/^[[:space:]]*-[[:space:]]<groupname>.$/,/^[[:space:]]{2}-[[:space:]][^-]/{/^[[:space:]]*-[[:space:]]/{s/^[[:space:]]{4}-[[:space:]]//p}; /^[[:space:]]*-[[:space:]]/d}'

PS Actually this white spaces in the group name ate a lot of time to find the way to deal with them.
